# pickling dict inherited class is missing internal values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, pickle

I've played around for a bit with the code and obviously the reason for the failure is that when setting `'wham'` the value is another instance of the class `TestDict` which works fine as long as i don't try to pickle and unpickle it.
Because if i do `self.test` is missing.

### Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    loads_a = loads(dumps_a)
  File "test.py", line 15, in __setitem__
    if self.test == False:
AttributeError: 'TestDict' object has no attribute 'test'
```

### The code:

```
from pickle import dumps, loads

class TestDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, test=False, data={}):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.test = test

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if self.test == False:
            pass
        return dict.__getitem__(self, k)

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if self.test == False:
            pass
        if type(v) == dict:
            super().__setitem__(k, TestDict(False, v))
        else:
            super().__setitem__(k, v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TestDict()
    a['wham'] = {'bam' : 1}
    b = TestDict(True)
    b['wham'] = {'bam' : 2}
    dumps_a = dumps(a)
    dumps_b = dumps(b)

    loads_a = loads(dumps_a)
    loads_b = loads(dumps_b)

    print(loads_a)
    print(loads_b)
```

The code works if not replacing `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` but i want to add extra functionality to those two specific functions.

I've also tried:

```
class TestDict(dict):
    __module__ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
```

Which sort of worked, as long as i don't nest `TestDict` within `TestDict` meaning i won't get to replace `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` in sub-parts of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#pickle.object.__reduce__) method:

```
class TestDict(dict):
    ...

    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), (self.test, dict(self))
```

Comment: Even better IMO, now i can pass along a number of attributes :D

Comment: Descided to go with this solution, it's more native and the rest of the code makes more sense with `__reduce__`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pickle` doesn't call the `__init__` method of the object when it does the unpicling, so the `self.test` variable is not created at the moment when it tries to set the items of the dictionary.

Apparently setting the attributes is staged after setting items of the dictionary.

One way to solve it is to add a class level attribute that will be overridden in the instances:

```
class TestDict(dict):
    test = False
    ...
```

Comment: There is no problem with [super](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super). Omitting the arguments is allowed in Python 3.

Comment: Dno why i didn't think of it but this works (don't know why this is voted negativly but i bumped it up.. running a few tests and will mark as solved if it works)

Comment: @Torxed it's actually a quirky behavior, because it depends on the order in which the pickle deserializes things. Apparently when you inherit a dictionary it will first populate it items using `__setitem__` and after that it will deserialize the `__dict__` of the object.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez Indeed, that's sort of the same conclusion i came to.